# Java : Out Of Memory Error when my application runs for longer time

Tags: java, multithreading, amazon-s3

I have a java application where i take files very small file (1KB) but large number of small file like in a minute i.e i am getting 20000 files in a minute.
I am taking file and uploading into S3 .

I am running this in 10 parallel threads .
Also i have to continuously run this application .

When this application runs for some days i get Out of memory error.

This is the exact error i get

```
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 347376 bytes for Chunk::new
# Possible reasons:
#   The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
#   In 32 bit mode, the process size limit was hit
# Possible solutions:
#   Reduce memory load on the system
#   Increase physical memory or swap space
#   Check if swap backing store is full
#   Use 64 bit Java on a 64 bit OS
#   Decrease Java heap size (-Xmx/-Xms)
#   Decrease number of Java threads
#   Decrease Java thread stack sizes (-Xss)
#   Set larger code cache with -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
# This output file may be truncated or incomplete.
#
#  Out of Memory Error (allocation.cpp:390), pid=6912, tid=0x000000000003ec8c
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_181-b13) (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.181-b13 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Core dump written. Default location: d:\S3FileUploaderApp\hs_err_pid6912.mdmp
#
```

Here is my java classes .
I am copying all classes so that it would be easy to investigate .

This is My Java Visual VM report Image

[image]

Adding My Sample Output

[image]

Updating Metaspace Image

[image]

This is my Main class

```
  public class UploadExecutor {
    private static Logger _logger = Logger.getLogger(UploadExecutor.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        _logger.info("----------STARTING JAVA MAIN METHOD----------------- ");
        /*
         * 3 C:\\Users\\u6034690\\Desktop\\TWOFILE\\xml
         * a205381-tr-fr-production-us-east-1-trf-auditabilty
         */
        final int batchSize = 100;
        while (true) {
            String strNoOfThreads = args[0];
            String strFileLocation = args[1];
            String strBucketName = args[2];
            int iNoOfThreads = Integer.parseInt(strNoOfThreads);
            S3ClientManager s3ClientObj = new S3ClientManager();
            AmazonS3Client s3Client = s3ClientObj.buildS3Client();
            try {
                FileProcessThreads fp = new FileProcessThreads();
                File[] files = fp.getFiles(strFileLocation);
                try {
                    _logger.info("No records found will wait for 10 Seconds");
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
                    files = fp.getFiles(strFileLocation);
                    ArrayList<File> batchFiles = new ArrayList<File>(batchSize);
                    if (null != files) {
                        for (File path : files) {
                            String fileType = FilenameUtils.getExtension(path.getName());
                            long fileSize = path.length();
                            if (fileType.equals("gz") && fileSize > 0) {
                                batchFiles.add(path);
                            }
                            if (batchFiles.size() == batchSize) {
                                BuildThread BuildThreadObj = new BuildThread();
                                BuildThreadObj.buildThreadLogic(iNoOfThreads, s3Client, batchFiles, strFileLocation,
                                        strBucketName);
                                _logger.info("---Batch One got completed---");
                                batchFiles.clear();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    // to consider remaining or files with count<batch size
                    if (!batchFiles.isEmpty()) {
                        BuildThread BuildThreadObj = new BuildThread();
                        BuildThreadObj.buildThreadLogic(iNoOfThreads, s3Client, batchFiles, strFileLocation,
                                strBucketName);
                        batchFiles.clear();
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    _logger.error("InterruptedException: " + e.toString());
                }
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                _logger.error("InterruptedException: " + t.toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the class where i build  Threads and shutdown executor .
So for every run i create new Executor service .

```
   public class BuildThread {

    private static Logger _logger = Logger.getLogger(BuildThread.class);

    public  void buildThreadLogic(int iNoOfThreads,AmazonS3Client s3Client, List<File> records,String strFileLocation,String strBucketName) {


        _logger.info("Calling buildThreadLogic method of BuildThread class");

        final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(iNoOfThreads);
        int recordsInEachThraed = (int) (records.size() / iNoOfThreads);
        int threadIncr=2;
        int recordsInEachThreadStart=0;
        int recordsInEachThreadEnd=0;

        for (int i = 0; i < iNoOfThreads; i++) {
            if (i==0){
                recordsInEachThreadEnd=recordsInEachThraed;
            }
            if (i==iNoOfThreads-1){
                recordsInEachThreadEnd=records.size();
            }

            Runnable worker = new UploadObject(records.subList(recordsInEachThreadStart, recordsInEachThreadEnd), s3Client,strFileLocation,strBucketName);
            executor.execute(worker);
            recordsInEachThreadStart=recordsInEachThreadEnd;
            recordsInEachThreadEnd=recordsInEachThraed*(threadIncr);
            threadIncr++;
        }

        executor.shutdown();
        while (!executor.isTerminated()) {
        }

        _logger.info("Existing buildThreadLogic method");
    }

}
```

And this is the class where i upload my Files into S3 and have run method

```
   public class UploadObject implements Runnable {

    private static Logger _logger;
    List<File> records;
    AmazonS3Client s3Client;
    String fileLocation;
    String strBucketName;

    UploadObject(List<File> list, AmazonS3Client s3Client, String  fileLocation, String strBucketName) {
        this.records = list;
        this.s3Client = s3Client;
        this.fileLocation=fileLocation;
        this.strBucketName=strBucketName;

        _logger = Logger.getLogger(UploadObject.class);
    }

    public void run() {
        uploadToToS3();
    }

    public void uploadToToS3() {
        _logger.info("Number of record to be uploaded  in current thread: : " + records.size());
        TransferManager tm = new TransferManager(s3Client);
        final MultipleFileUpload upload = tm.uploadFileList(strBucketName, "", new File(fileLocation), records);
        try {
            upload.waitForCompletion();
        } catch (AmazonServiceException e1) {
            _logger.error("AmazonServiceException " + e1.getErrorMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (AmazonClientException e1) {
            _logger.error("AmazonClientException " +  e1.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            _logger.error("InterruptedException " +  e1.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        } finally {
            _logger.info("--Calling TransferManager ShutDown--");
            tm.shutdownNow(false);

        }

        CleanUp CleanUpObj=new CleanUp();
        CleanUpObj.deleteUploadedFile(upload,records);
    }
}
```

This class used to create S3 client manager

```
public class S3ClientManager {

    private static Logger _logger = Logger.getLogger(S3ClientManager.class);

    public  AmazonS3Client buildS3Client() {

        _logger.info("Calling buildS3Client method of S3ClientManager class");
        AWSCredentials credential = new ProfileCredentialsProvider("TRFAuditability-Prod-ServiceUser").getCredentials();
        AmazonS3Client s3Client = (AmazonS3Client) AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion("us-east-1")
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credential)).withForceGlobalBucketAccessEnabled(true)
                .build();
        s3Client.getClientConfiguration().setMaxConnections(5000);
        s3Client.getClientConfiguration().setConnectionTimeout(6000);
        s3Client.getClientConfiguration().setSocketTimeout(30000);
        _logger.info("Exiting  buildS3Client method of S3ClientManager class");
        return s3Client;
    }
}
```

This is where i get files .

```
public class FileProcessThreads {

    public  File[] getFiles(String fileLocation)  {

        File dir = new File(fileLocation);
        File[] directoryListing = dir.listFiles();
        if (directoryListing.length > 0)
            return directoryListing;
       return null;

    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot run your code in my environment but I suggest to create memory dump using jmap. Here is a syntax for this command: jmap -dump:format=b,file=heap.bin <pid> Next, open this memory dump in Eclipse Memory Analyzer and see which objects are suspected.
You can create even two dumps in some intervals and compare them. In these way you'll see where you have more objects in the second dump.

Comment: can you upload your gc logs https://gceasy.io/ and share link of reports. I suspect your gc might be kicking in too frequently.

Comment: I do not have as of now gc log but i will try to collect it .Also there is a while loop in my main method will that cause any issue ?

Comment: Sudarshan, can you include the print of the metaspace (tab on right side of heap tab). The memory could be consumed by meta space, as the heap looks fine.

Comment: @fhofmann Updated that image as well

Comment: As far as I can see you are _not_ running in 10 threads, you are running in 10 threads per BuildThread and there can be many of those. I would suggest moving the executor to main and passing it in, sharing the same executor for all jobs. Then you do not need to stop it either, the threads can wait for more work.

Comment: Try to set -XX:MetaspaceSize=128M on your jVM. This should solve the OO memory problem, but you need review the code as commented by @ewrammer (and maybe you even need this change)

Comment: @ewramner yes i did try that ..But then some thread were not coming out at  all .And my application were busy some other thread ...And also i feel arrayList is not thread safe so it create Interuped Exception

Comment: @fhofmann can we set this while running jar ?

Comment: If a single executor service with 10 threads can't handle the load you can simply increase the number of threads to 50 or even 100 rather than spinning up multiple services where you lose control. If you run out of threads anyway you may have a bug so that some threads never complete. In that case you need to find that bug. Use jstack when the application seems to have hanged and see what the threads are doing.

Comment: @ewramner so i did what you have suggested.I tested this with just 50 files and 10 threads and my thread never came out ..There must be something wrong in my code.I created ExecutorService in main method and passed it into ThreaBuild class .Also i tried keeping TransferManager also in main method but got same result

Comment: Then I would suggest rewriting this so that you have a much simpler single-threaded class that just focuses on getting one file transferred correctly. When that works, run the same single-threaded class in parallel for multiple files using the standard thread pool class. Give each a single file to work with when you create it. Then when sending a single batch of files in parallel works, think about how to add additional tasks and optionally how to pool/reuse resources. That way you can debug one thing at a time.

Answer (score 11):

I am sorry not to address the original question on the memory leak, but your approach seems totally flawed to me. The `System.exit()` calls at `UploadObject` can be the cause of a resource leak but that's only the beginning. Amazon S3 `TransferManager` already has an internal executor service so you do not need your own multithreaded controller. I can't see how are you going to grant that each file is uploaded once and only once. You make a multiple uploads call and then delete all the files with disregard of whether there has been a failure during the upload and thus the files are not in S3. You try to distribute the files among the executors, this is unneccesary. Adding more threads on top of the `TransferManager` `ExecutorService` will not enhance your performance but only cause thrashing.

I would come with a different approach.

First a very simple main class which just starts a worker thread and waits for it to complete.

```
public class S3Uploader {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final String strNoOfThreads = args[0];
        final String strFileLocation = args[1];
        final String strBucketName = args[2];

        // Maximum number of file names that are read into memory
        final int maxFileQueueSize = 5000;

        S3UploadWorkerThread worker = new S3UploadWorkerThread(strFileLocation, strBucketName, Integer.parseInt(strNoOfThreads), maxFileQueueSize);

        worker.run();

        System.out.println("Uploading files, press any key to stop.");
        System.in.read();

        // Gracefully halt the worker thread waiting for any ongoing uploads to finish
        worker.finish();

        // Exit the main thread only after the worker thread has terminated
        worker.join();

    }

}
```

The worker thread will make use of a `Semaphore` to limit how many uploads are sent to the `TransferManager`, a custom file name queue `FileEnqueue` to read files constantly from the source directory, and a `ProgressListener` to follow up on the progress of each upload. If the loop runs out of files to read from the source directory it waits ten seconds and retries. Even the file queue may be unnecessary. Just listing the files inside the `while` loop of the worker thread may be enough.

```
import java.io.File;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

import com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException;

import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.TransferManager;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.TransferManagerBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.Upload;

public class S3UploadWorkerThread extends Thread {

    private final String sourceDir;
    private final String targetBucket;
    private final int maxQueueSize;
    private final AmazonS3Client s3Client;

    private Semaphore uploadLimiter;
    private boolean running;

    public final long SLEEP_WHEN_NO_FILES_AVAILABLE_MS = 10000l; // 10 seconds

    public S3UploadWorkerThread(final String sourceDir, final String targetBucket, final int maxConcurrentUploads, final int maxQueueSize) {
        this.running = false;
        this.sourceDir = sourceDir.endsWith(File.separator) ? sourceDir: sourceDir + File.separator;
        this.targetBucket = targetBucket;
        this.maxQueueSize = maxQueueSize;
        this.s3Client = S3ClientManager.buildS3Client();
        this.uploadLimiter = new Semaphore(maxConcurrentUploads);
    }

    public void finish() {
        running = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        running = true;

        final Map<String, Upload> ongoingUploads = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        final FileEnqueue queue = new FileEnqueue(sourceDir, maxQueueSize);
        final TransferManager tm = TransferManagerBuilder.standard().withS3Client(s3Client).build();

        while (running) {
            // Get a file name from the in memory queue
            final String fileName = queue.poll();
            if (fileName!=null) {
                try {
                    // Limit the number of concurrent uploads
                    uploadLimiter.acquire();
                    File fileObj = new File(sourceDir + fileName);
                    // Create an upload listener
                    UploadListener onComplete = new UploadListener(fileObj, queue, ongoingUploads, uploadLimiter);
                    try {
                        Upload up = tm.upload(targetBucket, fileName, fileObj);
                        up.addProgressListener(onComplete);
                        // ongoingUploads is  used later to wait for ongoing uploads in case a finish() is requested
                        ongoingUploads.put(fileName, up);
                    } catch (AmazonClientException e) {
                        System.err.println("AmazonClientException " +  e.getMessage());
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                // poll() returns null when the source directory is empty then wait for a number of seconds
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(SLEEP_WHEN_NO_FILES_AVAILABLE_MS);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } // fi
        } // wend

        // Wait for ongoing uploads to finish before exiting ending the worker thread
        for (Map.Entry<String,Upload> e : ongoingUploads.entrySet()) {
            try {
                e.getValue().waitForCompletion();
            } catch (AmazonClientException | InterruptedException x) {
                System.err.println(x.getClass().getName() + " at " + e.getKey());
            }
        } // next

        tm.shutdownNow();
    }
}
```

The `UploadListener` releases permits from the `Semaphore`, notify the file queue when an upload is complete and keeps track of ongoing uploads which must be waited for in case of an ordered stop is requested by the user. With a `ProgressListener` you can keep track of each successful or failed upload individually.

```
import java.io.File;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

import com.amazonaws.event.ProgressEvent;
import com.amazonaws.event.ProgressListener;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.Upload;

public class UploadListener implements ProgressListener {

    private final File fileObj;
    private final FileEnqueue queue;
    private final Map<String, Upload> ongoingUploads;
    private final Semaphore uploadLimiter;

    public UploadListener(File fileObj, FileEnqueue queue, Map<String, Upload> ongoingUploads, Semaphore uploadLimiter) {
        this.fileObj = fileObj;
        this.queue = queue;
        this.ongoingUploads = ongoingUploads;
        this.uploadLimiter = uploadLimiter;
    }

    @Override
    public void progressChanged(ProgressEvent event) {

        switch(event.getEventType()) {

        case TRANSFER_STARTED_EVENT :
            System.out.println("Started upload of file " + fileObj.getName());
            break;

        case TRANSFER_COMPLETED_EVENT:
            /* Upon a successful upload:
             * 1. Delete the file from disk
             * 2. Notify the file name queue that the file is done
             * 3. Remove it from the map of ongoing uploads
             * 4. Release the semaphore permit
             */
            fileObj.delete();
            queue.done(fileObj.getName());
            ongoingUploads.remove(fileObj.getName());
            uploadLimiter.release();
            System.out.println("Successfully finished upload of file " + fileObj.getName());
            break;

        case TRANSFER_FAILED_EVENT:
            queue.done(fileObj.getName());
            ongoingUploads.remove(fileObj.getName());
            uploadLimiter.release();
            System.err.println("Failed upload of file " + fileObj.getName());
            break;

        default:
            // do nothing
        }       
    }
}
```

This is a bolierplate sample for the file queue:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileFilter;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListSet;

public class FileEnqueue {

    private final String sourceDir;
    private final ConcurrentSkipListSet<FileItem> seen;
    private final ConcurrentSkipListSet<String> processing;
    private final int maxSeenSize;

    public FileEnqueue(final String sourceDirectory, int maxQueueSize) {
        sourceDir = sourceDirectory;
        maxSeenSize = maxQueueSize;
        seen = new ConcurrentSkipListSet<FileItem>();
        processing = new ConcurrentSkipListSet<>();
    }

    public synchronized String poll() {
        if (seen.size()==0)
            enqueueFiles();
        FileItem fi = seen.pollFirst();
        if (fi==null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            processing.add(fi.getName());
            return fi.getName();
        }
    }

    public void done(final String fileName) {
        processing.remove(fileName);
    }

    private void enqueueFiles() {
        final FileFilter gzFilter = new GZFileFilter();
        final File dir = new File(sourceDir);

        if (!dir.exists() ) {
            System.err.println("Directory " +  sourceDir + " not found");
        } else if (!dir.isDirectory() ) {
            System.err.println(sourceDir + " is not a directory");
        } else {

            final File [] files = dir.listFiles(gzFilter);

            if (files!=null) {

                // How many more file names can we read in memory
                final int spaceLeft = maxSeenSize - seen.size();

                // How many new files will be read into memory
                final int maxNewFiles = files.length<maxSeenSize ? files.length : spaceLeft;

                for (int f=0, enqueued=0; f<files.length && enqueued<maxNewFiles; f++) {
                    File fl = files[f];
                    FileItem fi = new FileItem(fl);
                    // Do not put into the queue any file which has been already seen or is processing
                    if (!seen.contains(fi) && !processing.contains(fi.getName())) {
                        seen.add(fi);
                        enqueued++;
                    }
                } // next
            }
        } // fi
    }

    private class GZFileFilter implements FileFilter {

        @Override
        public boolean accept(File f) {
            final String fname = f.getName().toLowerCase();         
            return f.isFile() && fname.endsWith(".gz") && f.length()>0L;
        }   
    }

}
```

And last your S3ClientManager:

```
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSStaticCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder;

public class S3ClientManager {

    public static AmazonS3Client buildS3Client() {

        AWSCredentials credential = new ProfileCredentialsProvider("TRFAuditability-Prod-ServiceUser").getCredentials();
        AmazonS3Client s3Client = (AmazonS3Client) AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion("us-east-1")
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credential)).withForceGlobalBucketAccessEnabled(true)
                .build();
        s3Client.getClientConfiguration().setMaxConnections(5000);
        s3Client.getClientConfiguration().setConnectionTimeout(6000);
        s3Client.getClientConfiguration().setSocketTimeout(30000);

        return s3Client;
    }
}
```

**Update 30/04/2019 add FileItem class**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class FileItem implements Comparable {

    private final String name;
    private final long dateSeen;

    public FileItem(final File file) {
        this.name = file.getName();
        this.dateSeen = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public long getDateSeen() {
        return dateSeen;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object otherObj) {
        FileItem otherFileItem = (FileItem) otherObj;
        if (getDateSeen()==otherFileItem.getDateSeen())
            return getName().compareTo(otherFileItem.getName());
        else if (getDateSeen()<otherFileItem.getDateSeen())
            return -1;
        else
            return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object otherFile) {
        return getName().equals(((FileItem) otherFile).getName());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return getName().hashCode();
    }

    public static final class CompareFileItems implements Comparator {

        @Override
        public int compare(Object fileItem1, Object fileItem2) {
            return ((FileItem) fileItem1).compareTo(fileItem2);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks This is what i was looking for ...I knew my java application is not good ..As of now i am facing error in `FileEnqueue` ..can not instantiate `FileItem fi = new FileItem(fl);`

Comment: Also we have InBuilt Progress Listener and then i wait for completion before deleting .So in that case i wont be losing the files or i wont be deleting the file without uploading into S3 .I agree your point about TransferManager

Comment: Cannot instantiate `FileItem fi = new FileItem(fl)`? That is a public class with a public constructor. What is the compiler complaining about?

Comment: Not sure which FileItem class have you imported. If its Apache commons, then FileItem is an Interface. So you have to use some concrete type like DiskFileItem.

Comment: I forgot to include the `FileItem` class in the reply. Just updated it.

Comment: That is perfect answer especially the part witch talks about threads and loop .

Answer (score 3):

What version of Java are you using and what are the parameters that you set for the garbage collector? Recently, I ran into an issue with our Java 8 applications running the default settings where over time they would eat up all of the memory the server had available. I fixed this by adding the following parameters to each application:

- `-XX:+UseG1GC` - makes the application use the G1 garbage collector.
- `-Xms32M` - set the minimum heap size to 32mb
- `-Xmx512M` - set the maximum heap size to 512mb
- `-XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=20` - sets the minimum heap ratio free when upsizing the heap
- `-XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=40` - sets the maximum heap ratio free when downsizing the heap

*Note that you should know the memory requirements and behavior of your application before configuring these parameters to avoid major performance issues.*

What happens is Java will keep allocating more memory from the server until it reaches the maximum heap size. Afterwards, it will run garbage collection to try to free space within the memory it has. This meant that we had 16 microservices increasing in size naturally over time without garbage collecting since they never reached the default maximum of 4gb. Before they could, the server ran out of RAM to give to the applications and the OutOfMemory errors began to happen. This was especially apparent in our application which read and parsed over 400,000 files per day.

Additionally, because the default garbage collector in Java 8 is the parallel garbage collector, the applications would never give memory back to the server. Changing these settings made our microservices manage their memory more efficiently and made them play nicely on the server by giving back memory they no longer needed.

[This](https://dzone.com/articles/choosing-the-right-gc) is the article that I found that helped me solve our issue. It describes everything I said above in more detail.

Comment: I have not set explicity any paramete that you have mentioned and i am using java 8 .Can i set this while running jar file ...?

Comment: Yes, my full command for running our applications is `java -XX:+UseG1GC -Xms32M -Xmx512M -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=20 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=40 -cp jars/*:libs/* com.example.MyMainClass`

Comment: G1 is built for large heaps, so with a 512M heap it may not be the best choice. Furthermore 512M is a very small heap, in particular if the program runs out of memory as it is. I rarely use less than 1024M even for small programs. The heap free ratios are very application dependent, so just picking a value from someone else may not be the best idea. I would recommend focusing on the program logic rather than the GC settings in this case.